# Is it possible to use faceAPI in linux

Tags: face-api

I am new to microsoft face API. Is it possible to use it in linux environment?

I could not find any documentation about it in their website.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use on any platform, there are samples provided in many programming languages in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/) that are supported on Linux to help you get started!

You just have to use the right endpoint and request valid parameters and you'll be fine working with any programming language on any platform.